# Regular powers in terms of falling powers: non-Stirling recursive approach

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am reading through Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, Patashnik) and they show you can express regular powers in terms of falling powers; starting with

$$
k^2 = k^\underline{2} + k^\underline{1}
$$

Then they go on to show $k^3$ and that a "simple calculation" reveals

$$
k^3 = k^\underline{3} + 3k^\underline{2} + k^\underline{1}
$$

I am having trouble understand what that simple calculation is. I also found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535978/expressing-powers-in-terms-of-falling-powers) which was some help; to quote

> It is easy to see that $n^1 = n^\underline{1}$ and $n^2 = n^\underline{2} + n^\underline{1}$. With these base cases, one can recursively express any normal power of $n^k$ as a sum of $n^\underline{k}$, yielding a $k$th order polynomial. Then, substitute falling-power-expansions for all terms of order less than $k$, expressing $n^\underline{k}$ as $n^k$ plus some lower-order falling powers. Rearrange to put $n^k$ on the LHS and all falling powers on the RHS. For example, one can find that $n^3 = n^\underline{3} + 3n^\underline{2} + n^\underline{1}$

I am trying this but obviously not understanding the process for $n^3$

$$
\begin{align}
n(n-1)(n-2) &= n(n^2 - 3n + 2) \\
&= n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n \\
-n^3 &= -3n(n-1) +n -2n \\
-n^3 &= -3n(n-1) -n \\
n^3 &= 3n(n-1) + n \\
n^3 &\ne 3n^\underline{2} +n^\underline{1}
\end{align}
$$

Which is clearly not correct.

Yes, there is a better way with Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind but I want to understand the "naive" way first.

Comment: The “simple calculation” is just expanding: $$k^{\underline 3}=k(k-1)(k-2)=k^3-3k^2+2k\\k^{\underline 2}=k(k-1)=k^2-k,\\k^{\underline 1}=k.$$

Comment: You seem to be assuming $n(n-1)(n-2)=0$ when you put $-n^3$ on one side. It is not true that $$-n^3=-3n(n-1)+n-2n$$

Comment: Quite right @ThomasAndrews, I see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that $n^1=n^{\underline1}$ and $n^2=n^{\underline2}+n^{\underline 1}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
n^{\underline3}&=n(n-1)(n-2)\\
&=n^3-3n^2+2n\\
&=n^3-3\left(n^{\underline2}+n^{\underline 1}\right)+2n^{\underline1}\\
&=n^3-3n^{\underline2}-n^{\underline1}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$n^3=n^{\underline3}+3n^{\underline2}+n^{\underline 1}\,.$$